# Diferencia al Inicializar valores de una clase?

Tags: c#, .net, poo

Tengo una clase con demasiadas variables, necesito inicializar los valores en vacio dependiendo su tipo de dato, veo que lo puedo hacer de dos maneras:

```
public class Documento
{
    public Document()
    {
        Tipo = "";
        Numero = "";
    }

    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

y de esta otra manera:

```
public class Documento
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; } = "";
    public string Numero { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Cual es la diferencia?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: En este caso ninguna, sería diferente si tu constructor no fuera vacío

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El objetivo que logras es el mismo, solo que aplica caracteristicas de versiones de c# diferentes

Usar el constructor para definir la inicializacion es compatible desde las primeras versiones de C#, en cambio usar la inicializacion de propiedades vas a necesitas c# 6 o superior

[Inicializadores de propiedades automáticas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers)

Pero en resumen son dos formas de lograr lo mismo